# Partitioning using dynamic values from table - Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning, partition

I want to create a table with partitioning that automatically adds a partition via a column name.

E.g. Phone numbers (should only take distinct values) and as new numbers are added to the column, the partition should create a partition (with the specific name would be preferable) such as "name of month"_"mobile number".

Adding the partition is tedious as there will be over 1,000 data to add each day for the partition. The partition may have to query and pull the data from another table.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-partitioning-084209.html. See interval partitioning: *Thus, Oracle automatically creates and maintains the partitions when you define an interval partitioning scheme.*

Comment: Isn't Interval partitioning done to Date or similar format values?